Novel about a girl who makes jewels with her emotions, dies, and goes back in time

She and her sister were held captive due to their ability to produce jewels.
In her first life, the main character awakens her ability after her sister's death and is held captive for her ability and then killed.
In her second life, she escapes and decides to either be adopted or married to enemies of people who held her captive.
Everyone loves her.
She learns magic.


Was this a physical book or a novel that you read online? When did you read it? And why did you add the [translation] tag?

A new user has attempted to edit this question, seemingly in response to my previous comment. If that person is you, and you've lost access to the account you used to post this question, please merge your accounts by following the instructions provided here. Once the accounts are merged, you'll regain the ability to edit this question without approval from others, post comments within this thread, and mark an answer as accepted, if you wish to do so.

The Villain's Daughter-in-Law, also The New Daughter-in-Law of the Villain Family

Luciel is a [Crystal Fairy]. Someone who can create jewelry when she feels strong emotions. She died after being exploited and returned to the past!
‘This time, I will never live like that.’
In order to avoid the worst future possible, she even proposed a contract marriage to the Empire’s top villain family.  But something became weird. The start of this relationship was definitely temporary.
“How about becoming my daughter instead of a daughter-in-law?”
“I always wish I had a granddaughter, this is just perfect.”
“When I grow up, I will marry my sister-in-law.”
How come they are doing this to me when they were said to be villians?
Besides…
“Whether it’s a jewel or a flower, it doesn’t matter to me what you make.”
The reaper of Bellstein.  The man who was in ruins in her past life said so with a fresh smile on his young face.
“If you get out of my sight, I’ll chase you to the end, Luciel.”

